# How do I pass touch events from a page view controller to the container controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following view controller setup:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
        transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: Constants.pageViewControllerOptions
    )
    
    pageViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    
    view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    addChild(pageViewController)
    pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    let vc = TableViewController()
    pageViewController.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    
}
```

And `TableViewController`:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private enum Constants {
        static let headerHeight: CGFloat = 210
    }
    
    let tableView = TouchTable()
    
    var scrollBlock: ((UIScrollView) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear


        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: Constants.headerHeight, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -Constants.headerHeight)
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        self.view = view
    }
    
}
```

`TouchTable` is like so:

```
class TouchTable: UITableView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

I have tried this code but it isn't passing touches to the view controller below. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```swift
class TouchTable: UITableView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

I think this code prevents `UIEvent` from being instantiated from within the table view so it's not that the event is failing to be passed, but the event is failing to be instantiated from your table view.

You could use the protocol/delegate pattern, but you could also use the `UIResponder` chain.

Have your parent view controller adopt and conform to a protocol:

```swift
@objc protocol EventFromChildVC: AnyObject {
    func didSelect(_ sender: ChildVC)
}

func didSelect(_ sender: ChildVC) {
    // passed event
}
```

And send the action from the child view controller:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(EventFromChildVC.didSelect(_:)), to: nil, from: self, for: nil)
}
```